# Getting error while connecting zend framework with MSSQL on linux machine

Tags: php, linux, windows, zend-framework, php-extension

I am getting an issue while doing database(MSSQL) connectivity with linux machine.

Its working fine on my Window environment. but not working on linux environment.

I am using following configuration for Linux in Zend framework.

I also added 4 sqlserver extension for Linux machine, but its not working.

```
extension="libessqlsrv.so"
extension="libessqlsrv_a.so"
extension="libessqlsrvS.so"
extension="libessqlsrv_ssl.so"

resources.db.adapter = pdo_mssql
resources.db.params.pdoType = dblib
resources.db.params.driver_options.PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
resources.db.params.host = pnpdevdb1.cbwvg2df689q.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com
resources.db.params.dbname = dbname
resources.db.params.username = "user"
resources.db.params.password = "pwd"
```

Please suggest how can i resolve it.

Comment: specifically what error are you getting?

Comment: Does your PHP have the appropriate mssql module installed? Check out `phpinfo();` to see.

Comment: I am using UBuntu linux machine and have not installed any extension for sql server connectivity. I searched on google, but i have not found any extension from there for Ubuntu 32 bit extnsions